# How to query multiple images in Gatsby from Strapi using Graphql

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I have set up a multiple media(images) field called pictures on my project content type on Strapi and I have added 2 projects with pictures containing 4 images each.
I want to query these images in Gatsby using Graphql.

This is my plugins array in gatsby-config.js

```
    plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
      options: {
        apiURL: `http://localhost:1337`,
        queryLimit: 1000,
        contentTypes: [`project`],
      },
    }]
```

This is my graphql query on localhost:8000/___graphql

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiProject {
    nodes {
      pictures {
        formats {
          thumbnail {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                src
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result I am getting

```
   {
  "data": {
    "allStrapiProject": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "pictures": [
            {
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": null
              }
            },
            {
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": {
                  "childImageSharp": {
                    "fluid": {
                      "src": "/static/eb8a7ee6108ecc0e6185aced82c3316b/b4216/167f320a448c2d6ff65acf179ee627e2.jpg"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": null
              }
            },
            {
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": null
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "pictures": [
            {
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": null
              }
            },
            {
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": null
              }
            },
            {
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": null
              }
            },
            {
              "formats": {
                "thumbnail": null
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

All of the thumbnails contain null except for one.

I have tried running 'gatsby clean' and sometimes get the query output to have same image urls in multiple places even though i don't have repeating images on Strapi.

Answer (score 3):

As of now, there is no "official" way to make it happen. But there is a workaround which creates a custom node in the build process. For a graphql query like below

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiPortfolio {
    edges {
      node {
        category {
          images {
            localFile {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid {
                  base64
                  tracedSVG
                  srcWebp
                  srcSetWebp
                  originalImg
                  originalName
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code given below creates the `localFile` node after `images`. The code should go in `gatsby-node.js`.

```
const { createRemoteFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

exports.onCreateNode = async ({ node, actions, store, cache }) => {
  const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions;

  if (node.internal.type !== null && node.internal.type === "StrapiPortfolio") {
    for (const category of node.category) {
      for (const image of category.images) {
        console.log(image);
        const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
          url: "http://localhost:1337" + image.url,
          store,
          cache,
          createNode,
          createNodeId: (id) => image.id.toString(),
        });

        if (fileNode) {
          image.localFile___NODE = fileNode.id;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Please note that you will have to customize the code depending on your needs. In my solution, I used two for loops because of my data structure. If you're unsure or just want to check if your custom code works, you can simply add a `console.log(node)` before the first if statement and a `console.log(image)` after the second for loop(in my case). That should give you an indication about your data structure and in which way you should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a  localFile___NODE.

First, you need to edit gatsby-node.js file.

```
const { createRemoteFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
 node,
 actions,
 store,
 cache,
 createNodeId,
}) => {
const { createNode } = actions

// replace ".sliderHome" for the name of multiple media in Strapi CMS
let sliderImages = node.sliderHome

// replace “StrapiHome” for your node type

if (node.internal.type === "StrapiHome") {
  if (sliderImages.length > 0) {
    // sliderImages.forEach(el => console.log(el))
    const images = await Promise.all(
      sliderImages.map(el =>
        createRemoteFileNode({
          url: `http://localhost:1337${el.url}`,
          parentNodeId: node.id,
          store,
          cache,
          createNode,
          createNodeId,
        })
       )
     )

    sliderImages.forEach((image, i) => {
      image.localFile___NODE = images[i].id
    })
   }
 }
}
```

later restart Gatsby and now this is your query

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiProject {
    nodes {
      pictures {
        localFile{
          childImageSharp{
            fluid(maxWidth: 1200){
              // or for gatsby use ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
              src 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this has worked for me to bring multiple images with a good quality I hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try below, replace the value you need to display:
Here I am the example for the user avatar

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiUser {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          avatar {
            publicURL
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
              src
              aspectRatio
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and:
`const poster = data.allStrapiUser.edges[0].node`

```
<Img fluid={{aspectRatio: 1.6, src: poster.avatar.publicURL}}/>
```