# Mapping array of images leads to the same image repeating on every instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Im trying to map an object from an array of arrayed images into an image gallery on separate product pages  (coming from strapi). The correct number of images appear but it repeats the same image over them. Even on product pages that shouldn't include that image in their respective array. examples - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zRTu.jpg

Ive checked the source and the image src links are all different versions of the same image. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEn1m.jpg

GraphIQL - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL5wQ.jpg

Any pointers on where im going wrong would be great! please let me know if you need any more info.

Code-

```
<div className="image-grid">
                {data.home.galleryImage.map((image, id, caption) => (
                    
                      <Image fluid={image.formats.medium.childImageSharp.fluid} alt="hh" key={id} class="galleryimg" thumbnail/> 
                   
                ))  
                }
                </div>
        </div>
```

GraphQL query -

```
export const query = graphql`
      query GetSingleHome($slug: String) {
        home: strapiHomes(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
        galleryImage {
          id 
          formats {
            medium {
              childImageSharp {
               fluid(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 250) {
                 ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
      }
    `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting properly the `key` value. `image` is the iterable object, is just a way of naming each index of your `galleryImage` so the `id`, doesn't stand as the `id` of the image itself.

Change it to:

```
<div className="image-grid">
  {data.home.galleryImage.map((image) => (
     <Image fluid={image.formats.medium.childImageSharp.fluid} alt="hh" key={image.id} class="galleryimg" thumbnail/>  
   ))}
</div>
```

To access the nested image properties, you need to access its child properties, like the way you do in `image.formats`, accessing to `formats` position, but using `image.id`.

For further details, you can check the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

In addition, if the loop is printing the same image, internally the `id` is not correctly set from GraphQL when created the data node from Strapi. You can customize the GraphQL node schema to add custom parameters in order to bypass this limitation using different APIs provided by Gatsby, `createRemoteFileNode` should fit your requirements.

```
 const { createRemoteFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);
    
    exports.onCreateNode = async ({ node, actions, store, cache }) => {
      const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions;
    
      if (node.internal.type !== null && node.internal.type === "StrapiPortfolio") {
        for (const category of node.category) {
          for (const image of category.images) {
            console.log(image);
            const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
              url: "http://localhost:1337" + image.url,
              store,
              cache,
              createNode,
              createNodeId: (id) => image.id.toString(),
            });
    
            if (fileNode) {
              image.localFile___NODE = fileNode.id;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

*Source: [How to query multiple images in Gatsby from Strapi using Graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745591/how-to-query-multiple-images-in-gatsby-from-strapi-using-graphql)*

Depending on your data structure, you may need to change the loop and some other parameters. In this case, images are inside a `category` node so, it has to be inferred by nesting two different loops.

The idea is to loop through all your image nodes and add the `localFile___NODE` field with:

```
  image.localFile___NODE = fileNode.id;
```

The `id` is previously created in:

```
  createNodeId: (id) => image.id.toString(),
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of combinations for createRemoteFileNode code but i cant get my head around what i need to sub into it to get it working, always end up with "Cannot query field "localFile" on type "File"".

StrapiPortfolio changes to GetSingleHome & i use  "for (const medium of formats.medium)" ?